# Notepad++ add specific string each line

Tags: notepad++

I have to add specific string each line in Notepad++.  How can I do?  Thanks!

Before:

```
I am a boy A.
I am a girl A.
```

After:

```
I am a boy A boy.
I am a girl A girl.
```

Comment: Regarding the edit - you'd have to explain better. Duplicating the last word is easy, but now it isn't any more. Can there be only one word? Is it **always** `A`, or can it be something else? Is it any word, or just `boy` and `girl`?

Answer (score 1):

Open the *Replace* window and check *Regular expression*:

Find what: `\b(\w+)\.$`
Replace with: `\1 \1.`

`\b(\w+)\.$` is a simple regex that matches the last word before the period. The word is captured into the first group (`\1` or `$1` both work in Notepad++), so it can be used twice while replacing.

Comment: I tip my hat to you. Learned a new thing. Thank you very much!

Comment: @M42 - Of course it will. The question was edited - that's why I added the comment - the question became too obscure. (I see that you've added a variant with two words, but it still only a guess)

Answer (score 0):

CTRL + H

at search method select

```
Expandend (\n, \r, \t, \0, \x...)
```

and with the search fields you select

```
At search for you enter : \n 
At Replace by you enter : My specific string \n
```

Or use macro's

- menu > Macro > start recording
- Hit [END]
- Press left arrow <-
- press down CTRL + SHIFT and hit the <- left arrow once so the last word is selected
- press right key ->
- hit SPACE
- press CTRL + V
- menu > Macro > stop recording
- menu > Macro > Save Macro
- Name: Name of the macro
- Key combination of which keys will trigger the macro
- Press OK.

Answer (score 0):

After you've checked the regular expression choice:

Find: `(\S+)\s(\S+)\.$`
replace: `$1 $2 $1.`